# how transform stdin input to some json field in list of lines using jq

Tags: json, jq, stdin

I need a utility that

- read from stdin, split as lines
- write to stdout json object, {"cmd": "In", "lines": [lines from stdin]}

I heard jq being quite powerful, how to acheive above with jq or similar tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `jq` reads from `stdin`. The `-R` flag lets you read raw input streamed linewise. Using `[inputs]` in combination with the `-n` flag lets you collect the lines into an array.

```bash
… | jq -Rn '{cmd: "In", lines: [inputs]}'
```

Comment: I need output to be one line. Found `-c` in `jq --help`.  By the way, does jq support write to a socket, eg, `127.0.0.1:8080`.

Comment: @qeatzy The `-c` compacts the output to one line, the `-j` flag gets rid of trailing newlines. Support for I/O is minimal in general, and currently only supports reading from stdin, and writing to stdout and stderr.

Comment: `jq` itself doesn't write to a socket, but whatever *calls* `jq` can arrange for its standard output to be the socket you want to write to.